# issue in while controller jmeter

Tags: jmeter, blazemeter

replicate steps:

```
1. -ThreadGroup
2. --loop controller (Count 10)
3. ---counter
4. ----while controller(`${__javaScript("${RegexValue}".indexOf("olum") == -1 && ${Counter}<5,)}`)
5. -----Counter
6. -----dummy sampler
7. ------regex `"c([A-z]+)nId` (extracting oulm value)
```

**Question**: in jmeter during run if while controller conditions are met it is stopping both the loops. is there a way in which i can only stop the inner while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I don't see any [Samplers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#samplers) which would be the children of the Loop Controller so when the While Controller ends the Loop Controller will end as well
2. You don't need these "Counters" as there are special variables holding the values of the current loop, they are:

   - `${__jm__Loop Controller__idx}` - for the Loop Controller
   - `${__jm__While Controller__idx}` - for the While Controller
3. You should be using either [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) function in order to define your condition

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i was not intializing the while loop.